# LINQPad Dump(toDataGrid) doesn't display until end of execution

Tags: c#, linqpad

I'm working on a little script in LINQPad for automatic batch mailing. Despite having the data being validated by the script, I would like to have it checked by someone and his confirmation. And, the following is my attempt at the sanity check :

```
var datasource = Enumerable.Range(0, 10) //not actual data
    .Dump("Data", true);

var message = string.Format("Please enter {0} to confirm or -1 to cancel : ", datasource.Count());
var container = new DumpContainer(message).Dump("Last Confirmation");
do
{
    var result = Console.ReadLine();
    container.Content = (container.Content as string) + result;

    if (result == "-1") return;
    if (result == datasource.Count().ToString()) break;

    container.Content = (container.Content as string) + "\n" + message;
} while (true);

//do stuffs...
```

Most of it work great, except that the `datasource` is not being dumped until end of execution which defeat whole purpose of this block of code. How can I make the Data tab display immediately?

Please note that I intended to dump the `datasource` into a new `DataGrid` tab, as it cannot be easily scanned through nor exported to excel.

Comment: Dumping to grids requires a message loop which requires the main thread to be unblocked. Will have to think on this further.

Comment: @JoeAlbahari How about making .Dump to a grid use DoEvents or similar? Hackish, for sure, but may be the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed in v4.51.03 (in beta at time of writing).

Use the new Util.ReadLineAsync method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int x = await Util.ReadLineAsync<int> ("Enter a number");
    Enumerable.Range (0, x).Dump (x + " integers", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cheat I found to get around this problem : `Hyperlinq`

```
void Main()
{
    var datasource = Enumerable.Range(0, 10) //not actual data
        .Dump("Data", true);

    Console.Write("Please confirm everything is correct : "); //couldnt manage to get them to dump on same line
    new Hyperlinq(() => DoStuffs(datasource), "Do Stuffs").Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public void DoStuffs(IEnumerable<int> datasource)
{
    datasource.Select(x => 2 * x).Dump("Altered Data", true);


    new Hyperlinq(() => DoStuffs(datasource), "Do More Stuffs").Dump();
}
```

There is also a minor annoyance/bug that is introduced with this cheat. When there isn't enough rows in the datagrid to occupy the entire area an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is thrown and dump to the result panel, but doesn't break the flow of execution.